# Countability of the word “gameplay”

Tags: countability, countable-nouns

I have searched all the online dictionaries, and they all say that the word “gameplay” is uncountable. The problem is that they don’t have the up-to-date meaning of the word “gameplay”.

Can we use the word “gameplay” with the indefinite article? For example:

> 1. This was **a** fun **gameplay**, I killed all the zombies.

In the above example, I intend to say that an instance of it was fun. Do we need the indefinite article there?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gameplay.

Comment: What do you think is the “up to date” meaning of gameplay? If you mean the way the kids are using it on Twitch as the current meaning, keep in mind that slang doesn’t follow the rules.

Comment: @ColleenV it is probably slang, even young native English speakers use it that way (“a gameplay”)

Comment: Do you have an example from somewhere online? I’m a pretty avid gamer, and if I saw “a gameplay” I would think the person speaking wasn’t a native English speaker. I’m old and would like to know what the kids are rapping these days, yo.

Comment: @ColleenV I don’t have it at the moment, but I will definitely ping you whenever I encounter the players use it that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an abstract noun meaning "the way that a player interacts with the game" (The collection of rule, goals and how those rules can be changed.)  It is not likely to be used countably.

It doesn't mean "an instance of playing a game"  Your example could  "That was a fun game; I killed all the zombies." or "Also, it could be That was a fun playthrough." (suggested by ColleenV in comment)

Comment: Also, it could be *That was a fun [playthrough](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/playthrough).*